# HERE API: Heatmap from KML

Tags: here-api

I'd like to display a kmlfiles with just points on a HERE map as a heatmap.

I've seen the heatmap example and KML examples but could someone help me combine the two so I can make a heatmap from my KML file?

Comment: Do you have a _concrete_ question? SO is not a message board. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Transform your KML data to an array of [nokia.maps.heatmap.Overlay.DataPoint](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/maps/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.heatmap.Overlay.DataPoint.html) elements. The data set can then be used as in the [Heat Map Example](http://developer.here.com/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-js/data-visualization/map-with-density-heat-map.html)

The precise transformation will depend on  where in the KML your data is held (and whether you need to pass in values as well, but the following XSLT should help get you started:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
    data = [
        <xsl:for-each select="kml/Document/Folder/Placemark/Point">
        {
            <xsl:variable name="coordinates">
                <xsl:value-of select="*" />
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="longitude">                                                     
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($coordinates,',')"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="latitude">                                                      
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($coordinates,','),',')"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            latitude: <xsl:value-of select="$latitude" />,
            longitude: <xsl:value-of select="$longitude" />
            }
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    ];      
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alter `kml/Document/Folder/Placemark/Point` as necessary if your points aren't in a folder for example.